# Setting text color onCreateView works but not onClick

Tags: android, nullpointerexception, textview

I'm currently working hard on learning both Java & Android, and I've come upon a problem that I simply cannot solve myself.

This is the class:

```
public class Lock extends Fragment implements OnClickListener {

    BluetoothAdapter mBluetoothAdapter = BluetoothAdapter.getDefaultAdapter();
    int mBluetoothState = 0;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lock, container, false);

        ImageView mBluetoothImage = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.BluetoothIcon);
        TextView mBluetoothText = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.BluetoothText);

        if (mBluetoothAdapter == null) {
            // Add popup later - your device doesn't support bluetooth
            mBluetoothImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluetooth_icon);
            mBluetoothText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue1));
            mBluetoothState = 0;
        }
        else {
            if (!mBluetoothAdapter.isEnabled()) {
                // Device supports bluetooth, enable.
                mBluetoothImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluetooth_icon2);
                mBluetoothState = 1;
            }
            else {
                // Bluetooth is enabled, disable.
                mBluetoothImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluetooth_icon3);
                mBluetoothText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue1));
                mBluetoothState = 2;
            }
        }
        mBluetoothImage.setOnClickListener(this);

        return rootView;
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        ImageView mBluetoothImage = (ImageView)v.findViewById(R.id.BluetoothIcon);
        TextView mBluetoothText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.BluetoothText);

        if (mBluetoothState == 0) {
            // Add popup later - your device doesn't support bluetooth
            mBluetoothText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red1));
        }
        else if (mBluetoothState == 1) {
            // Device supports bluetooth, enable.
            mBluetoothAdapter.enable();
            mBluetoothState = 2;
            mBluetoothImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluetooth_icon3);
            mBluetoothText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue1));
        }
        else {
            // Bluetooth is enabled, disable.
            mBluetoothAdapter.disable();
            mBluetoothState = 1;
            mBluetoothImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluetooth_icon2);
            mBluetoothText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray1));
        }

    }
}
```

In the OnCreateView method, both mBluetoothImage and mBluetoothText changes as it should, and in the onClick method mBluetoothImage changes as it should.
But the mBluetoothText throws an error at line 60, 69 or 74, depending on the mBluetoothState.

```
mBluetoothText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.red1));
mBluetoothText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.blue1));
mBluetoothText.setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.gray1));
```

What I don't understand is that the onCreateView works, but it doesn't in onClick, and it's only the Text that doesn't work, can you guys help?

edit - here is the error log:

```
11-04 14:26:06.618: W/dalvikvm(7959): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x415cece0)
11-04 14:26:06.618: E/AndroidRuntime(7959): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-04 14:26:06.618: E/AndroidRuntime(7959): Process: com.example.bikey, PID: 7959
11-04 14:26:06.618: E/AndroidRuntime(7959): java.lang.NullPointerException
11-04 14:26:06.618: E/AndroidRuntime(7959):     at com.example.bikey.Lock.onClick(Lock.java:74)
11-04 14:26:06.618: E/AndroidRuntime(7959):     at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4438)
11-04 14:26:06.618: E/AndroidRuntime(7959):     at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:18439)
11-04 14:26:06.618: E/AndroidRuntime(7959):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
11-04 14:26:06.618: E/AndroidRuntime(7959):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
11-04 14:26:06.618: E/AndroidRuntime(7959):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
11-04 14:26:06.618: E/AndroidRuntime(7959):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5153)
11-04 14:26:06.618: E/AndroidRuntime(7959):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-04 14:26:06.618: E/AndroidRuntime(7959):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
11-04 14:26:06.618: E/AndroidRuntime(7959):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:796)
11-04 14:26:06.618: E/AndroidRuntime(7959):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:612)
11-04 14:26:06.618: E/AndroidRuntime(7959):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Comment: Can you post the logcat?

Comment: logcat errors have been added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `onClick()`, you're calling `findViewById()` on the view `v` that was clicked on. The views you're trying to find are not children of the clicked view, and `null` is returned.

Move the `mBluetoothImage` and `mBluetoothText` as member variables in your fragment, initialie them in your `onCreateView()` and use them in `onClick()`.

For example:

```
private ImageView mBluetoothImage;
private TextView mBluetoothText;

@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.lock, container, false);

    mBluetoothImage = (ImageView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.BluetoothIcon);
    mBluetoothText = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.BluetoothText);
```

... and remove the `findViewById()` initialization in `onClick()`.

Comment: So right you are, thank you very much.
I will accept this answer in 2 min when I can :)